# How to replace an execute ActionForward method

Tags: java, jsp

I'm using struts for the very first time,

The thing is, I've an ActionForward execute method in my java class,
and in my jsp page I invoke another action `fooAction` that it's also declared in my java class

```
tag:page namePag="<%=pagnum%>"
urlAccion="/foo.do?dispatch=fooAction"
idParam="numPage" />
```

Despite this, every action in my jsp is directed to the `execute` method, and if I change the name of the `execute` method, the page redirects to a blank page,
So how can I remove/rename the `execute` method without affecting the functionality

Comment: what is the version of struts , you are using?

Comment: I'm using v1.1 of struts

Answer (score 1):

```
In struts V1.1, by default it executes the "Execute Method". If you are very particular to redirect the request to a defined page.

Do this change in action mapping attribute
<action path="/fooAction" type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction"  parameter="/pages/fooActionJsp.jsp"/> 

Point the jsp to the appropriate page using the parameter
```